# $anchorScroll() mooving the whole html body

Tags: angularjs

**I'm using this angularjs well known function to display my anchored div:**

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
     $location.hash(id);
     $anchorScroll();
  }
```

**This is the view :**

```
<div id="foo-{{$index}}"></div>
<a href="" ng-click="scrollTo('foo-4')">Scroll to #foo</a>
```

Now, the problem :

It is working, but, the whole body of the page is mooving when cliking. So i can't see my fixed top navbar any more.

maybe you already have encoutered this problem ?

I'd like my html body not to be able to moove when cliking an anchor, how should i do ?.

Thank you a lot if you have any idea.

Comment: body{
   position:fixed;
} Works, but i can't scroll the body page any more ...

Comment: provide code on plunker

Comment: @nick put `position: fixed` only for the header and not whole `body`

Comment: Thanks a lot i'm trying to fix my bootstrap navbar

Comment: This is my labo, i've fixed the bootstrap, but mooving to anchor still have a problem  : http://localhost/football/#/vignettes#foo-4   You may click on Scroll to #foo